# GIT / GITHUB Branches (~$ nautilus)

Tags: linux, git, github

I am a GIT beginner, and I have a little doubt that has been hunting me for a while. I want to know if new branches will be reflected in your standard OS directory.

For example, suppose that you have a master branch and decide to start a development in a new branch. When you are editing this new branch from the terminal, it is clear that you will not change anything in the master, unless that you merged it. HOWEVER, which branch will be reflected if do you decide to open it from your file browser ( ~$ nautilus )...

Answer (score 0):

Whatever branch you have checked out is what will you will see.